# C++ сервер - клиент

Tags: c++, linux, windows, книги

Подкиньте литературки по поводу общения клиент - сервер - клиент. Отправка текстовой информации... Очень интересно с поддержкой `linux`  и `win`

Comment: [Реально полезные материалы](http://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имеется довольно хорошая библиотека для этой цели: boost::asio. Boost - большой сборник высококачественных библиотек C++. Авторитет boost в мире C++ настолько высок, что решения boost включаются в стандарт языка C++. Boost позволяет писать кроссплатформенный код. В документации на boost::asio имеется пример готового TCP-сервера и TCP-клиента.

Answer (score 2):

Еще можно посмотреть в сторону QT, собственная документация по библиотеке очень хороша, так же есть примеры. Но с точки зрения универсальности применения - Boost более интересен.

Из книг мне попалась "Создание сетевых приложение в среде Linux. Руководство разработчика", автор Шон Уолтон. Я ее использовал как вводное пособие в создание сетевых приложений.